# Issues with php file not rendering at all when in test environment

Tags: php, html, mysql

I built a basic application that is pulling data from an outside source and storing it in the database from PHP and it is running on the same server as my next step.

My next step is retrieving this information and using it in the HTML output for the dashboard. The code I came up with is below, and it is the most basic query and variable system I can think of, yet when I put it into my test environment, it doesn't work. I would consider myself relatively new to PHP in this application, but from all the research I have done, this seems to be the best route. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried several different styles for making a SQL connection, and even tried storing the variables globally, but had no luck. Also, I have put this code through several formatters to ensure everything is correct, as well as going over by hand after to try and make sure it didn't add something it shouldn't have.

```
<?php

// Retrieve Morning Record Data

$conn = new mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT date, team, dollar_amount, car_count FROM morning";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

    // output data into variables

    $dateb = $result["date"];
    $teamb = $result["team"];
    $damountb = $result["dollar_ammount"];
    $ccountb = $result["car_count"];
}
else {
    echo "Error Retrieving Data/No Data Found in morning table";
}

$conn->close();

// Retrieve Lunch Record Data

$conn = new mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT date, team, dollar_amount, car_count FROM lunch";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

    // output data into variables

    $datel = $result["date"];
    $teaml = $result["team"];
    $damountl = $result["dollar_ammount"];
    $ccountl = $result["car_count"];
}
else {
    echo "Error Retrieving Data/No Data Found in lunch table";
}

$conn->close();

// Retrieve Lunch Record Data

$conn = new mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT date, team, dollar_amount, car_count FROM dinner";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

    // output data into variables

    $dated = $result["date"];
    $teamd = $result["team"];
    $damountd = $result["dollar_ammount"];
    $ccountd = $result["car_count"];
}
else {
    echo "Error Retrieving Data/No Data Found in dinner table";
}

$conn->close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <div>
    <div>
    <h1>Drive Thru Records</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>Breakfast Record</h2>
        <h3>Team</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $teamb;
?></p>
        <h3>Dollar Amount</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $damountb;
?></p>
        <h3>Car Count</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $ccountb;
?></p>
        <h3>Date</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $dateb;
?></p>
    </div>
        <div>
    <h2>Lunch Record</h2>
        <h3>Team</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $teaml;
?></p>
        <h3>Dollar Amount</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $damountl;
?></p>
        <h3>Car Count</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $ccountl;
?></p>
            <h3>Date</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $datel;
?></p>
    </div>
        <div>
    <h2>Dinner Record</h2>
        <h3>Team</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $teamd;
?></p>
        <h3>Dollar Amount</h3>
        <p>?php echo $damountd; ?></p>
        <h3>Car Count</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $ccountd;
?></p>
            <h3>Date</h3>
        <p><?php
echo $dated;
?></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </head></html>
```

The expected result would be that the program pulls the data from the database, assign it to the variables, and then uses echo to place in the correct spot in the HTML.

At this point when I run the code in my test environment, all I get is a page of the code, and no logs or anything to help on screen, I'm stuck, please help!

***UPDATE***

I went back and look at everything I had downloaded for php, and realized I didn’t download any of the extra components needed. Once I did so, I reloaded the page, and got a 500 ERROR, screenshot below.

[image]

Also, I started a new environment on AWS and have gotten the php_info() function to work, but not my program, I still get the 500 Error. And when I check the logs I get this:

[Fri Feb 01 19:21:20.163557 2019] [:error] [pid 14423] [client 73.169.82.233:63540] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function php_info() in /var/www/html/index.php:1\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 1

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman I am a little confused by what you are saying.

Comment: @ Nigel Ren It is a .php extension

Comment: You need to make sure your web server understands what `.php` is and that it needs to run those as a PHP script. If you don't have a PHP module these pages won't run, your server will just consider them to be plain text files with no particular meaning. Setting up a PHP module depends on what server you've got in place.

Comment: My earlier remark is about your use of `mysqli`. You use `new mysqli(...)` which is good, but then revert to the awkward procedural style when making calls. These are way more verbose, and way more error prone.The same code can be re-written in the form `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` to `$conn->query($sql)` and so on with no change in functionality, but a ton if readability improvement.

Comment: @tadman I have apache installed to run web application, is this what you mean by PHP modules. Also, I do PHP and MySQL installed on the server, I have another PHP application that runs from the command line and is working. Also, thank you for the tip, I'll start using that new form. Thank you.

Comment: You need to ensure that your Apache httpd server is configured *with the PHP module* because it probably isn't. At this point this question is better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) as it pertains to getting your server running, but keep in mind this is a very common problem and there's probably already tons of answers there that address the situation you're facing.

Comment: Please see update above.

Comment: At least it's running your code now. Next step is to check your error logs because something's broken. Error 500 is almost always an error in your PHP code.

Comment: I checked the error log and added it to the topic

Comment: php_info isn't the right name of the function. There is no underscore. It's just `phpinfo()`. See here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: @Kondos Johnson I don't see that function in my code anywhere though? So I don't know where the function is coming from.

Comment: Did you check `/var/www/html/index.php`, that's where the error says php_info is being used.

Comment: That is where the code that is above is stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since this has been up for a while I figured I would roughly explain what I did to fix this in hope it might help others who run into similar issues later.

So basically what I ended up doing, based off of suggestions from individuals here, I used prepared statements and placeholder values to mitigate the risk of SQL injection bugs. After that I assigned each individual variable in PHP that I was needing to use in the HTML so I could reference it later when building the template file. I know this is not how most people would recommend this, but I feel it helps me collect my thoughts a bit more and be able to visualize things, and then I can go back and optimize the code later by removing the PHP variable assignment section and placing them directly into the HTMl.

And as far as the error that I posted goes, it comes down to bad code. And I had to do more research to ensure things were structured properly. Thank you to everyone who gave me suggestions and material to look into.

Let me know if you have any questions though, thank you!